# Как отредактировать значения, занесенные в БД?

Tags: mysqli, php, база-данных, if

Всё удаляю) Вот так может яснее станет.

```
<?php
include ('dbcon.inc.php');//Коннектимся к БД
db_con();
include ('vivodupd.inc.php');//Тут форма которая принимает в себя данные для радактирования
vivodupd();
//это запрос,айдишник в него поступает методом GET 
//  $sql = "SELECT compos,fileob,vk,TfN,fN,id FROM top ORDER BY id='$upd' DESC";

//echo $_GET['upd']; Если сделать так то выведет нужную цифру 
//ВОПРОС.ГДЕ ОБЪЯВИТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ $upd В ИФЕ ЧТОБЫ ВСЁ ЗАРАБОТАЛО?НУ ИЛИ Я ЧТО ТО НЕ ТАК ДЕЛАЮ
//ВОТ ТАК НИЧЕГО НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ
if ( $_POST['compos']
    ){

    $compos = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['compos'],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $fileob = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fileob'],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $vk = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['vk'],ENT_QUOTES)));
     $TfN = $_FILES['uf']['tmp_name'];
            $fN= $_FILES['uf']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($TfN,$fN);

$sql="UPDATE
            top
            SET
            compos = '".$compos."',
            fileob = '".$fileob."',
            vk = '".$vk."'
            WHERE
            id = '$upd'";           
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    header("Location: http://www.way-up.ru"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: структуру таблицы top в студию.

Comment: @Сашка, подозреваю что проблема в ИД. Проверьте перед update-om:

if(intval($upd)>0)

{  ..update!...}

Comment: попробуйте во 2-м if  вывести echo "мое upd= ".$_GET['upd']; Посмотрите что выведется после равно. Если значение нужнок, то перепреоделите переменную $upd.

Comment: Второй иф хоть убей не хочет работать с этой $upd а вот так работает

$sql="UPDATE
            top
            SET
            compos = '$compos',
            fileob = '$fileob',
            vk = '$vk'
            WHERE
            vk = '$vk'";
НО если оставить так то , будут заменяться все записи с таким VK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил ответ

По анологии можно предположить, что у Вас такая ситуация: в SET надо прописать ещё другие поля(смотрите их название в таблице БД), из формы передать значения в переменные $fileob и $vk. Выполнить update (только разберитесь с экранированием кавычками, мне кажется, что Ваш пример может не работать)

```
            $sql="UPDATE
            top
            SET
            compos = '".$compos."',
            fileob = '".$fileob."',
            vk = '".$vk."'
            WHERE
            id = $upd;";

if ( $_POST['compos']
    ){

$upd = $_GET['upd'];//попробуйте объявить переменную здесь

    $compos = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['compos'],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $fileob = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fileob'],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $vk = stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['vk'],ENT_QUOTES)));
     $TfN = $_FILES['uf']['tmp_name'];
            $fN= $_FILES['uf']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($TfN,$fN);

$sql="UPDATE
            top
            SET
            compos = '".$compos."',
            fileob = '".$fileob."',
            vk = '".$vk."'
            WHERE
            id = '$upd'";           
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    header("Location: http://www.way-up.ru"); 
}
```

Comment: А что в переменной $compos? Похоже, что какие-то проблемы с кодировкой.

Comment: ололо, кавычки-то кто ставить будет, я чтоль?)

Comment: Вот пример работающего SQL запроса, Александр, сверьте со своим в плане синтаксиса, тем более что MySQL Вам об этом и пишет. И всё должно быть хорошо.

UPDATE `barada`.`storeactions` SET `aid` = 'comment_publish_action',
`type` = 'comment',
`callback` = 'comment_publish_action' WHERE `storeactions`.`aid` = 'comment_publish_action11';

Comment: Я подкорректировал в ответе экранирование переменных, попробуйте так.

Comment: Синтаксис вроде правильный.Факт в том что один запрос работает а другой нет...

Comment: Проверяйте в php файле строку $sql, где-то там ошибка с ковычками
Вставте переменную так '".$compos."' и т.п.